# FileSystemWatcher not working in Debain Buster Raspberry Pi

Tags: c#, linux, mono, debian

I have problem running `FilesystemWatcher` on Raspberry Pi with Debian Buster. `Filesystemwatcher` event is not fired and doesn't respond to any changes. The same code works fine for earlier Raspbain/Debian versions. I using mono to run the C# code.

```
greenlamp = new FileSystemWatcher()
{
    Path = Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + Path.Combine("sys", "class", "gpio", "gpio25"),
    Filter = "value",
    NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite
};
orangelamp = new FileSystemWatcher()
{
    Path = Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + Path.Combine("sys", "class", "gpio", "gpio13"),
    Filter = "value",
    NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite
};
optosensor = new FileSystemWatcher(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + Path.Combine("sys", "class", "gpio", "gpio12"), "value");

// Configure event handlers
redlamp.Changed += Redlamp_Changed;
redlamp.Created += Redlamp_Changed;               
redlamp.Deleted += Redlamp_Changed;
redlamp.Renamed += Redlamp_Changed;
greenlamp.Changed += Greenlamp_Changed;
orangelamp.Changed += Orangelamp_Changed;
optosensor.Changed += Optosensor_Changed;

// Enable event handlers
redlamp.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
greenlamp.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
orangelamp.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
optosensor.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

Comment: just a guess, but did you check you have the required permissions to watch the file system

Comment: running as a root user and event tried forcing permission